# estimating entropy/randomness as fail-safe mechanism

Tags: entropy

Real-world encryption systems are often not broken algorithmically but because the implementation has a bug. Sometimes the bug only happens in circumstances that could not have been foreseen, such as weak random numbers, or an error in a library causing e.g. predictable IVs.

So I wonder, are there workable methods of estimating randomness or entropy that could be helpful to detect (a subset of) actual failures in cryptographic systems?

As a simple example, such an estimator could be fed with consecutive CTR IVs and alert higher protocol layers when there is an apparent failure, because all IVs are identical for example. Or an estimator could be fed with encrypted DES output to detect a bug in the implemention.

Comment: Do you mean this would be installed in production installations, and executed periodically somehow?  Or are you suggesting a test harness that an implementer could wire in to "certify" the implementation?

Comment: I mean in production installations, and preferably executed continually (so cost is important). Take as example CBC mode AES used for repeated messages - monitoring the IV value for randomness continously would allow the sender to stop sending when a catastrophic IV failure is detected.

Comment: Regarding failure modes: An example of a failure mode could be a compiler bug that causes the IV value not to be calculated at all, but isntead being left at it's previous value, or using some semi-random data garbage left on the stack etc. The original program might be secure and correct while being tested, and might malfucntion somewhere else. The idea is having an extra failsafe mechanism, not something that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: The motivation for my question is that it is one thing to implement a reasonable generator for IV values that seems to work (i.e. encryption and decryption work), but hard to actually verify it - the encryption would work just as well with bogus IV values, but security would be completely lost. These cases are hard to catch using traditional testing techniques - apart from visually looking at IVs, there is little to verify their soundness.

Comment: Even this sounds implementation dependent.  Encryption algorithms don't throw standardized errors  - they're just math, working on numbers, and they don't fail in that way. What does it mean if it fails? Who looks at this data?  Where is the error generated?  You could certainly put this in a specific implementation, but I don't see how it would be a generic solution.

Comment: @JohnDeters I think he means e.g. check that something has gone wrong with the entropy supply algorithmically, in the same way that TRNG's need to do some tests on their output periodically to verify they haven't failed. It's an interesting question but it seems unlikely such an estimator exists, unless you are willing to run statistical tests on terabytes of data to detect a potential flaw. The problem is there just isn't enough data to assert that "this IV is not random, abort the mission", you need **a lot** more samples to conclude anything about what you are seeing.

Comment: I can see this working somewhat as a one-off implementation test bench, but it just doesn't seem doable to do those verifications constantly with any degree of accuracy. The old quote rings true: "that's the problem with randomness - you can never be sure".

Comment: The purpose is not to detetc true randomness with any accuracy, but to detect likely failure of randomness. It's probably better to wrongly detect a random string as not random enough and take an emergency brake then to use a failing entropy source. I agree that the accuracy is a problem - I don't think false positives would be a problem, but I am afraid the number of actual failures that could be detected is too low to be of any practical use. Still, maybe I am wrong, and then it would be nice to know.

Comment: So if it detected six values in a row that were all fewer than 10 bits apart, or all zeroes, etc. I still think it would be too specialized to catch much. You also have to weigh it against the risk of an incorrect (buggy) implementation.

Comment: Interesting link, using an entropy estimator can be dangerous: http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/338

Answer (score 1):

Such practices are commonly applied to results of some random number generators, but less often to other applications.

### There is one very common such fail-safe test

NIST's FIPS 140-2 requires very simple contiguous test for random number generation: store previous generated block and compare. Only if the block is different it is assumed that the RNG did not fail.

From FIPS 140-2 4.9.2:

> Continuous random number generator test. If a cryptographic module employs Approved or non- Approved RNGs in an Approved mode of operation, the module shall perform the following continuous random number generator test on each RNG that tests for failure to a constant value.

### More entropy tests

The standard (FIPS 140-2) used to require more tests (mono bit test, poker test, runs test, long runs test). These tests give fairly good estimate of if input appears random. These were decommissioned, because they work better with NDRBG than RNGs required by the standard (see [FIPS 140-2 Annex C](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402annexc.pdf) if you need details), and because for some cases it is excessive requirement to produce 20000 bits for analysis (it may be that you just needed one 128-bit key). AIS31 standard used to evaluate true random number generators uses some very similar tests.

### Used in practice

These tests are useful against some hardware random bit generators and for this reason, Linux rngd program is running the tests (previously part of FIPS 140-2) to ensure quality of entropy gotten (for example from /dev/hwrng) and to ignore inputs which appear non-random.

You may use Linux rngtest program to apply these tests to data of your choice, for instance, examine output of (possibly) buggy encryption software.